# What is exactly sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neuraxle

I can't figure out how the `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` works exactly.

There are a few explanation in the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). For example what do they mean by:

> Pipeline of transforms with a final estimator.

To make my question clearer, what are `steps`? How do they work?

**Edit**

Thanks to the answers I can make my question clearer:

When I call pipeline and pass, as steps, two transformers and one estimator, e.g:

```
pipln = Pipeline([("trsfm1",transformer_1),
                  ("trsfm2",transformer_2),
                  ("estmtr",estimator)])
```

What happens when I call this?

```
pipln.fit()
OR
pipln.fit_transform()
```

I can't figure out how an estimator can be a transformer and how a transformer can be fitted.

Comment: From what I have understood, pipeline helps you automize several step of the learning process. Such as the training and testing of models or feature selection... So if you want to mix a regression then use it to feed a classifier for instance, your steps will be the training of that regression and then of the classifier. edit: add details

Comment: http://queirozf.com/entries/scikit-learn-pipeline-examples I found this helpful

Answer (score 233, accepted):

**Transformer** in scikit-learn - some class that have fit and transform method, or fit_transform method.

**Predictor** - some class that has fit and predict methods, or fit_predict method.

**Pipeline** is just an abstract notion, it's not some existing ml algorithm. Often in ML tasks you need to perform sequence of different transformations (find set of features, generate new features, select only some good features) of raw dataset before applying final estimator.

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html) is a good example of Pipeline usage.
Pipeline gives you a single interface for all 3 steps of transformation and resulting estimator. It encapsulates transformers and predictors inside, and now you can do something like:

```
    vect = CountVectorizer()
    tfidf = TfidfTransformer()
    clf = SGDClassifier()

    vX = vect.fit_transform(Xtrain)
    tfidfX = tfidf.fit_transform(vX)
    predicted = clf.fit_predict(tfidfX)

    # Now evaluate all steps on test set
    vX = vect.fit_transform(Xtest)
    tfidfX = tfidf.fit_transform(vX)
    predicted = clf.fit_predict(tfidfX)
```

With just:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
])
predicted = pipeline.fit(Xtrain).predict(Xtrain)
# Now evaluate all steps on test set
predicted = pipeline.predict(Xtest)
```

With pipelines you can easily perform a grid-search over set of parameters for each step of this meta-estimator. As described in the link above. All steps except last one must be transforms, last step can be transformer or predictor.
**Answer to edit**:
When you call `pipln.fit()` - each transformer inside pipeline will be fitted on outputs of previous transformer (First transformer is learned on raw dataset).  Last estimator may be transformer or predictor, you can call fit_transform() on pipeline only if your last estimator is transformer (that implements fit_transform, or transform and fit methods separately), you can call fit_predict() or predict() on pipeline only if your last estimator is predictor. So you just can't call fit_transform or transform on pipeline, last step of which is predictor.

Comment: What do you mean by `predicted = pipeline.fit(Xtrain).predict(Xtrain)`?

Comment: @farhawa, predicting classes on training set.

Comment: fit returns object on which you called it, so fit().predict() is equivalent to fit_predict()

Comment: Why doesnt this have more votes?  It should be a blog post.

Comment: What if you need to apply different transformations to each column of the table of predictors? Like you have a column with 15 classes, another column with 11 classes and then the rest are floating values that you want to scale between 0 and 1 using the formula "(sample-mean of col.) / std.dev. of col."? How can Pipelines can help in these set-ups?

Comment: @iamgin, Interface of most of scikit-learn transformers doesn't allow to choose needed columns that we want to transform. But you can write your own "Item Selector", that will help you to feed transformer only with needed columns. Here is a good example with ItemSelector and FeatureUnion http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py

Comment: In the first example, don't you want to avoid fitting again with the test set? Shouldn't it only be calling transform instead of fit_transform? And similarly, does pipeline predict internally call fit_transform or just transform? Can it be controlled?

Comment: I still try to get the basic idea of Pipelines(). Isn't it just an ordinary function which you define manually yourself? Like every other arbitrary function?

Comment: @IbraimGaniev, I don't really understand the benefit of a pipeline. Can you explain what a pipeline does what writing a function cannot do? Or maybe what does a pipeline do better then a normal function?

Comment: The answer talks only about `fit_transform`ing or `predict`ing for train and test sets separately. How do I change the code, if I want to `.fit` or `.fit_transfrom` for train set and only use `.transform` and `.predict` on test sets?

Answer (score 26):

I think that M0rkHaV has the right idea. Scikit-learn's pipeline class is a useful tool for encapsulating multiple different transformers alongside an estimator into one object, so that you only have to call your important methods once (`fit()`, `predict()`, etc). Let's break down the two major components:

1. **Transformers** are classes that implement both `fit()` and `transform()`. You might be familiar with some of the sklearn preprocessing tools, like `TfidfVectorizer` and `Binarizer`. If you look at the docs for these preprocessing tools, you'll see that they implement both of these methods. What I find pretty cool is that some estimators can also be used as transformation steps, e.g. `LinearSVC`!
2. **Estimators** are classes that implement both `fit()` and `predict()`. You'll find that many of the classifiers and regression models implement both these methods, and as such you can readily test many different models. It is possible to use another transformer as the final estimator (i.e., it doesn't necessarily implement `predict()`, but definitely implements `fit()`). All this means is that you wouldn't be able to call `predict()`.

As for your edit: let's go through a text-based example. Using LabelBinarizer, we want to turn a list of labels into a list of binary values.

```
bin = LabelBinarizer()  #first we initialize

vec = ['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog'] #we have our label list we want binarized
```

Now, when the binarizer is fitted on some data, it will have a structure called `classes_` that contains the unique classes that the transformer 'knows' about. Without calling `fit()` the binarizer has no idea what the data looks like, so calling `transform()` wouldn't make any sense. This is true if you print out the list of classes before trying to fit the data.

```
print bin.classes_
```

I get the following error when trying this:

```
AttributeError: 'LabelBinarizer' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

But when you fit the binarizer on the `vec` list:

```
bin.fit(vec)
```

and try again

```
print bin.classes_
```

I get the following:

```
['cat' 'dog']


print bin.transform(vec)
```

And now, after calling transform on the `vec` object, we get the following:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

As for estimators being used as transformers, let us use the `DecisionTree` classifier as an example of a feature-extractor. Decision Trees are great for a lot of reasons, but for our purposes, what's important is that they have the ability to rank features that the **tree** found useful for predicting. When you call `transform()` on a Decision Tree, it will take your input data and find what **it** thinks are the most important features. So you can think of it transforming your data matrix (n rows by m columns) into a smaller matrix (n rows by k columns), where the k columns are the k most important features that the Decision Tree found.

Comment: What's the difference between `fit()` and `transform()` is the Transformers? , how estimators can be used as transformers?

Comment: `fit()` is the method you call to fit or 'train' your transformer, like you would a classifier or regression model. As for `transform()`, that is the method you call to actually transform the input data into the output data. For instance, calling `Binarizer.transform([8,2,2])` (after fitting!) might result in `[[1,0],[0,1],[0,1]]`. As for using estimators as transformers, I'll edit a short example into my answer.

Answer (score 18):

> ML algorithms typically process tabular data. You may want to do preprocessing and post-processing of this data before and after your ML algorithm. A pipeline is a way to chain those data processing steps.

## [What are ML pipelines and how do they work?](https://www.neuraxio.com/en/blog/neuraxle/2019/10/26/neat-machine-learning-pipelines.html)

A pipeline is a series of steps in which data is transformed. It comes from the old "pipe and filter" design pattern (for instance, you could think of unix bash commands with pipes “|” or redirect operators “>”). However, pipelines are objects in the code. Thus, you may have a class for each filter (a.k.a. each pipeline step), and then another class to combine those steps into the final pipeline. Some pipelines may combine other pipelines in series or in parallel, have multiple inputs or outputs, and so on. We like to view [Pipelining Machine Learning](https://www.neuraxle.org/) as:

- [Pipe and filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/pipes-and-filters). The pipeline’s steps process data, and they manage their inner state which can be learned from the data.
- [Composites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Pipelines can be nested: for example a whole pipeline can be treated as a single pipeline step in another pipeline. A pipeline step is not necessarily a pipeline, but a pipeline is itself at least a pipeline step by definition.
- [Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). A pipeline step's output may be sent to many other steps, and then the resulting outputs can be recombined, and so on. Side note: despite pipelines are acyclic, they can process multiple items one by one, and if their state change (e.g.: using the fit_transform method each time), then they can be viewed as recurrently unfolding through time, keeping their states (think like an RNN). That’s an interesting way to see pipelines for doing online learning when putting them in production and training them on more data.

### Methods of a Scikit-Learn Pipeline

Pipelines (or steps in the pipeline) **must have those two methods**:

- “[fit](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.fit)” to learn on the data and acquire state (e.g.: neural network’s neural weights are such state)
- “[transform](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.transform)" (or "predict") to actually process the data and generate a prediction.

It's also possible to call this method to chain both:

- “[fit_transform](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.fit_transform)” to fit and then transform the data, but in one pass, which allows for potential code optimizations when the two methods must be done one after the other directly.

## [Problems of the sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline class](https://www.neuraxio.com/en/blog/scikit-learn/2020/01/03/what-is-wrong-with-scikit-learn.html)

> Scikit-Learn’s “pipe and filter” design pattern is simply beautiful. But how to use it for Deep Learning, AutoML, and complex production-level pipelines?

Scikit-Learn had its first release in 2007, which was a [pre deep learning era](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/Awesome-Deep-Learning-Resources#trends). However, it’s one of the most known and adopted machine learning library, and is still growing. On top of all, it uses the Pipe and Filter design pattern as a software architectural style - it’s what makes Scikit-Learn so fabulous, added to the fact it provides algorithms ready for use. However, it has massive issues when it comes to do the following, which we should be able to do in 2020 already:

- **Automatic Machine Learning (AutoML),**
- **Deep Learning Pipelines,**
- **More complex Machine Learning pipelines.**

### Solutions that we’ve Found to Those Scikit-Learn's Problems

For sure, Scikit-Learn is very convenient and well-built. However, it needs a refresh. Here are our solutions with [Neuraxle](https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle) to make Scikit-Learn fresh and useable within modern computing projects!

- [Inability to Reasonably do Automatic Machine Learning (AutoML)](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#inability-to-reasonably-do-automatic-machine-learning-automl)

  - [Problem: Defining the Search Space (Hyperparameter Distributions)](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-defining-the-search-space-hyperparameter-distributions)
  - [Problem: Defining Hyperparameters in the Constructor is Limiting](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-defining-hyperparameters-in-the-constructor-is-limiting)
  - [Problem: Different Train and Test Behavior](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-different-train-and-test-behavior)
  - [Problem: You trained a Pipeline and You Want Feedback on its Learning.](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-you-trained-a-pipeline-and-you-want-feedback-statistics-on-its-learning)
- [Inability to Reasonably do Deep Learning Pipelines](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#inability-to-reasonably-do-deep-learning-pipelines)

  - [Problem: Scikit-Learn Hardly Allows for Mini-Batch Gradient Descent (Incremental Fit)](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-scikit-learn-hardly-allows-for-mini-batch-gradient-descent-incremental-fit)
  - [Problem: Initializing the Pipeline and Deallocating Resources](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-initializing-the-pipeline-and-deallocating-resources)
  - [Problem: It is Difficult to Use Other Deep Learning (DL) Libraries in Scikit-Learn](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-it-is-difficult-to-use-other-deep-learning-dl-libraries-in-scikit-learn)
  - [Problem: The Ability to Transform Output Labels](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-the-ability-to-transform-output-labels)
- [Not ready for Production nor for Complex Pipelines](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#not-ready-for-production-nor-for-complex-pipelines)

  - [Problem: Processing 3D, 4D, or ND Data in your Pipeline with Steps Made for Lower-Dimensional Data](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-processing-3d-4d-or-nd-data-in-your-pipeline-with-steps-made-for-lower-dimensionnal-data)
  - [Problem: Modify a Pipeline Along the Way, such as for Pre-Training or Fine-Tuning](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-modify-a-pipeline-along-the-way-such-as-for-pre-training-or-fine-tuning)
  - [Problem: Getting Model Attributes from Scikit-Learn Pipeline](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-getting-model-attributes-from-scikit-learn-pipeline)
  - [Problem: You can't Parallelize nor Save Pipelines Using Steps that Can't be Serialized "as-is" by Joblib](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/scikit-learn_problems_solutions.html#problem-you-can-t-parallelize-nor-save-pipelines-using-steps-that-can-t-be-serialized-as-is-by-joblib)

### Additional pipeline methods and features offered through [Neuraxle](https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle)

Note: if a step of a pipeline doesn’t need to have one of the fit or transform methods, it could inherit from [NonFittableMixin](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.NonFittableMixin) or [NonTransformableMixin](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.NonTransformableMixin) to be provided a default implementation of one of those methods to do nothing.

As a starter, it is possible for pipelines or their steps to also **optionally define those methods**:

- “[setup](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.setup)” which will call the “setup” method on each of its step. For instance, if a step contains a TensorFlow, PyTorch, or Keras neural network, the steps could create their neural graphs and register them to the GPU in the “setup” method before fit. It is discouraged to create the graphs directly in the constructors of the steps for several reasons, such as if the steps are copied before running many times with different hyperparameters within an Automatic Machine Learning algorithm that searches for the best hyperparameters for you.
- “[teardown](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.teardown)”, which is the opposite of the “setup” method: it clears resources.

The **following methods are provided by default** to allow for managing hyperparameters:

- “[get_hyperparams](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.get_hyperparams)” will return you a dictionary of the hyperparameters. If your pipeline contains more pipelines (nested pipelines), then the hyperparameter’ keys are chained with double underscores “__” separators.
- “[set_hyperparams](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.set_hyperparams)” will allow you to set new hyperparameters in the same format of when you get them.
- “[get_hyperparams_space](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.get_hyperparams_space)” allows you to get the space of hyperparameter, which will be not empty if you defined one. So, the only difference with “get_hyperparams” here is that you’ll get statistic distributions as values instead of a precise value. For instance, one hyperparameter for the number of layers could be a `RandInt(1, 3)` which means 1 to 3 layers. You can call `.rvs()` on this dict to pick a value randomly and send it to “set_hyperparams” to try training on it.
- “[set_hyperparams_space](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html#neuraxle.base.BaseStep.set_hyperparams_space)” can be used to set a new space using the same hyperparameter distribution classes as in “get_hyperparams_space”.

---

For more info on our suggested solutions, read the entries in the big list with links above.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd

class TextTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    Преобразование текстовых признаков
    """
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None, *parg, **kwarg):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.key]
    

class NumberTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    Преобразование числовых признаков
    """
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[[self.key]]



def fit_predict(model, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    vec_tdidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word', norm='l2')
    
    text = Pipeline([
                    ('transformer', TextTransformer(key='clear_messages')),
                    ('vectorizer', vec_tdidf)
                    ])
    word_numeric = Pipeline([
                    ('transformer', NumberTransformer(key='word_count')),
                    ('scalar', StandardScaler())
                    ])
    word_class = Pipeline([
                    ('transformer', NumberTransformer(key='preds')),
                    ('scalar', StandardScaler())
                    ])
    # Объединение всех признаков
    features = FeatureUnion([('Text_Feature', text),
                             ('Num1_Feature', word_numeric),
                             ('Num2_Feature', word_class)
                            ])
    
    # Классификатор
    clf = model
    
    # Объединение классификатора и признаков
    pipe = Pipeline([('features', features),
                     ('clf',clf)
                     ])
    
    # Обучение модели
    pipe_fit=pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    # Предсказание данных
    preds = pipe_fit.predict(X_test)
    
    return preds, pipe_fit
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].