# How to standardize data with sklearn's cross_val_score()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation, standardized

Let's say I want to use a LinearSVC to perform k-fold-cross-validation on a dataset. How would I perform standardization on the data?

The best practice I have read is to build your standardization model on your training data then apply this model to the testing data.

When one uses a simple train_test_split(), this is easy as we can just do:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y)

clf = svm.LinearSVC()

scalar = StandardScaler()
X_train = scalar.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scalar.transform(X_test)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
```

How would one go about standardizing data while doing k-fold-cross-validation? The problem comes from the fact that every data point will be for training/testing so you cannot standardize everything before cross_val_score(). Wouldn't you need a different standardization for each cross validation?

The docs do not mention standardization happening internally within the function. Am I SOL?

EDIT: This post is super helpful: [Python - What is exactly sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091376/python-what-is-exactly-sklearn-pipeline-pipeline)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) to combine both of the processes and then send it into the cross_val_score().

When the `fit()` is called on the pipeline, it will fit all the transforms one after the other and transform the data, then fit the transformed data using the final estimator. And during `predict()` (Only available if last object in pipeline is an estimator, otherwise `transform()`) it will apply transforms to the data, and predict with the final estimator.

Like this:

```
scalar = StandardScaler()
clf = svm.LinearSVC()

pipeline = Pipeline([('transformer', scalar), ('estimator', clf)])

cv = KFold(n_splits=4)
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv = cv)
```

Check out various examples of pipeline to understand it better:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#examples-using-sklearn-pipeline-pipeline