# Using scaler in Sklearn PIpeline and Cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation

I previously saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446501/how-to-standardize-data-with-sklearns-cross-val-score) with code like this:

```
scalar = StandardScaler()
clf = svm.LinearSVC()

pipeline = Pipeline([('transformer', scalar), ('estimator', clf)])

cv = KFold(n_splits=4)
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv = cv)
```

My understanding is that: when we apply scaler, we should use **3** out of the 4 folds to **calculate** mean and standard deviation, then we apply the mean and standard deviation to all 4 folds.

In the above code, how can I know that Sklearn is following the same strategy? On the other hand, if sklearn is not following the same strategy, which means sklearn would **calculate** the mean/std from all 4 folds. Would that mean I should not use the above codes?

I do like the above codes because it saves tons of time.

Answer (score 9):

In the example you gave, I would add an additional step using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`:

```
folds = 4

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=(1/folds), random_state=0, stratify=y)

scalar = StandardScaler()
clf = svm.LinearSVC()

pipeline = Pipeline([('transformer', scalar), ('estimator', clf)])

cv = KFold(n_splits=(folds - 1))
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, cv = cv)
```

I think best practice is to only use the training data set (i.e., `X_train, y_train`) when tuning the hyperparameters of your model, and the test data set (i.e., `X_test, y_test`) should be used as a final check, to make sure your model isn't biased towards the validation folds. At that point you would apply the same `scaler` that you fit on your training data set to your testing data set.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry that I cant upvote due to my reputation yet. I will once I have enough.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is done properly; this is one of the reasons for using pipelines: all the preprocessing is fitted only on training folds.

---

Some references.

[Section 6.1.1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline-chaining-estimators) of the User Guide:

> **Safety**
>   Pipelines help avoid leaking statistics from your test data into the trained model in cross-validation, by ensuring that the same samples are used to train the transformers and predictors.

The note at the end of [section 3.1.1 of the User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics):

> **Data transformation with held out data**
>   Just as it is important to test a predictor on data held-out from training, preprocessing (such as standardization, feature selection, etc.) and similar data transformations similarly should be learnt from a training set and applied to held-out data for prediction:
>   ...code sample...
>   A Pipeline makes it easier to compose estimators, providing this behavior under cross-validation:
>   ...

Finally, you can look into the source for `cross_val_score`.  It calls `cross_validate`, which clones and fits the estimator (in this case, the entire pipeline) on each training split.  [GitHub link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e895b42abe8d8d09105cbb82dc2cbba7/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L238).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can I see the logic of this implementation then?

Comment: I've added some references.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Sorry that I can't upvote yet. I will once I got more reputation.