# How to transform sklearn pipeline to normal code?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have this sklearn code from one [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-text-classification-in-python-using-spacy/):

```
pipe = Pipeline([("cleaner", predictors()),
                 ('vectorizer', bow_vector),
                 ('classifier', classifier)])
```

I want to transform it to normal code, something like this:

```
X_train = predictors.fit_transform(X_train)
X_train = bow_vector.fit_transform(X_train)
classifier.fit(X_train)
```

But I constantly get errors. Quick reading of the documentation didn't help

UPD

My exact code is

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df['X'] 
ylabels = df['y']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, ylabels, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

List of punctuation marks

```
punctuations = string.punctuation
```

Natural Language Processing engine

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

List of stop words

```
stop_words = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
```

Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser, NER and word vectors

```
parser = English()
```

Tokenizer

```
def spacy_tokenizer(sentence):
    # Creating an token object
    mytokens = parser(sentence)

    # Lemmatizing each token and converting each token into lowercase
    mytokens = [ word.lemma_.lower().strip() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in mytokens ]

    # Removing stop words
    mytokens = [ word for word in mytokens if word not in stop_words and word not in punctuations ]

    # return preprocessed list of tokens
    return mytokens
```

First element of pipeline

```
class predictors(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        # Cleaning Text
        return [clean_text(text) for text in X]

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        return {}
```

Basic function to clean the text

```
def clean_text(text):
    # Removing spaces and converting text into lowercase
    return text.strip().lower()
```

Comment: Well, what are the errors? And what is your exact code? I would need to now the data types of your variables

Comment: You should be able to call all these methods on `pipe`, e.g. `X_train = pipe.fit_transform(X_train)`. There should be no need to "disassemble" the pipeline if all you want to do is use it. [sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) docs

Comment: Related: [Python - What is exactly sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091376/python-what-is-exactly-sklearn-pipeline-pipeline)

Comment: I understand that I can do all operation in the pipeline at once, but I want to dig deeper and understand what happens with X_train step by step, to do this I want to do the first operation first, then look at X_train, then do the second operation and so on

Comment: I want to post my code, but stack overflow says: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Mostly the code is from the tutorial

Comment: Split your code into logical blocks and add explanations before each block. That way the ratio between code and text should balance out and you should be able to post it.

Comment: @sokolov0 the goal is to post a [mre], not the whole code

Comment: @sokolov0 also, what is the full error you are getting?

Comment: @Lomtrur I added code

Comment: @Ralf is it okay, or I should post a shorter code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

```
tfidf_vector = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = spacy_tokenizer)

cleaner = predictors()

X_train_cleaned = cleaner.transform(X_train)

X_train_transformed = tfidf_vector.fit_transform(X_train_cleaned)

classifier = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')

classifier.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train)

cleaner = predictors()

X_test_cleaned = cleaner.transform(X_test)

X_test_transformed = tfidf_vector.transform(X_test_cleaned)
```