# sklearn pipelines with fit_transfrom or predict objects instead of fit objects

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

[This example on sklearn website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html) and [this answer to sklearn pipelines on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33094099/11814996) uses and talks only about using `.fit()` or `.fit_transform()` methods in Pipleines.

But, how do I use .predict or .transfrom methods in Pipelines. let's say I have pre-processed my train data, searched for best hyper-parameters and trained an LightGBM model. I would now like to predict on new data, instead of doing all the aforementioned things manually, I want to do them all one-after-one, according to the [definition](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

> Sequentially apply a list of transforms and a final estimator.
> Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they
> must implement fit and transform methods. The final estimator only
> needs to implement fit.

But, I only want to implement `.transform` methods on my validation(or test) data and some more functions(or classes) that take pandas Series(or DataFrame or numpy array) and return processed one, then finally implement `.predict` method of my LightGBM, which would use the hyper-parameters I already have.

I currently have nothing, since I don't know how to include methods of classes properly( like
`StandardScaler_instance.transform()`) and more such methods.!

How do I do this or what have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build your pipeline, which will include the LightGBM model and train the pipeline on your (pre-processed) train data.

With code, it could look like this for example:

```
import lightgbm
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Create some train and test data
X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

# Define pipeline with scaler and lightgbm model
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('lightgbm', lightgbm.LGBMClassifier())])

# Train pipeline
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions with pipeline (with lightgbm)
print("Predictions:", pipe.predict(X_test))

# Evaluate pipeline performance
print("Performance score:", pipe.score(X_test, y_test))
```

**Output:**

```
Predictions: [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0]
Performance score: 0.84
```

So to answer your questions:

> But, how do I use .predict or .transfrom methods in Pipelines.

- You don't have to use .transform, as the pipeline handles the transforms of your input data with the supplied transformers automatically. That's why in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) it mentions:

> Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they
> must implement fit and transform methods.

- You can use .predict as shown in the code example with your test data.

Instead of the StandardScaler I used in this example, you can provide the pipeline with your custom transformer, but it has to implement a .transform() and .fit() method the pipeline can call and the output of the transformer needs to match the required input of the lightgbm model.

**Update**

You can then provide arguments for different steps of the pipeline as explained in the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit):

> ****fit_paramsdict of string -> object** Parameters passed to the `fit` method of each step, where each parameter name is prefixed such that
> parameter `p` for step `s` has key `s__p`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. I have a doubt though. If a have objects whose instance and methods take arguments. for example, I create a lightgbm instance with some arguments, which I presume can be included in Pipleine you have shown above. But, how do if pass arguments to fit method, like validation sets(not test set) and my custom evaluation metric.

Comment: I have this doubt, because I presume pipe.fit() doesn't accept all those arguments and I also wonder how if there are other objects whose .fit() methods take different arguments? is there any way I can specify the different arguments for each step of the pipeline during .fit and .predict or .transform?

Comment: I meant to ask, is there any way I can have a Pipleine use different arguments for different step, for both fit method and predict or transfrom method if applicable.

Comment: Yes, you can use different arguments for each step in the pipeline. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit) to see, how you can provide the arguments for instance during the fit() method call. I updated my answer with that information too.

Comment: I had checked documentation right before writing those comments. the .fit method there wasn't of much help.

Comment: I got it. Huge thanks again for your time and your effort.

Comment: @NaveenKumar no worries, I'm glad I could help!