# How do I convert my object type data to numeric in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like below. Some of the attributes are in object type data. I want to convert them to numeric tye data. but when I use pd.to numeric function, all the object type data converts to 'nan'

```
                                          Flow ID    Source IP  ...  Idle Min   Class
    523320       10.42.0.211-10.42.0.1-3145-53-17  10.42.0.211  ...         0  BENIGN
    502082       10.42.0.151-10.42.0.1-9436-53-17  10.42.0.151  ...         0  BENIGN
    579158  192.229.173.173-10.42.0.42-80-50469-6   10.42.0.42  ...         0  BENIGN
    59163       10.42.0.211-10.42.0.1-39702-53-17  10.42.0.211  ...         0  Malwre
    217478       10.42.0.151-10.42.0.1-4616-53-17  10.42.0.151  ...         0  Malwre
```

The data type is shown below

```
    Flow ID              object
    Source IP            object
    Source Port           int64
    Destination IP       object
    Destination Port      int64

    Idle Mean           float64
    Idle Std            float64
    Idle Max              int64
    Idle Min              int64
    Class                object
```

Now I want to use all my data and convert all the data into int or float.

Comment: So what kind of int would this be 10.42.0.211?

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: @Carsten Actually I have no idea, I wanted to use this dataset for Machine Learning. So I wanted to convert this data.

Comment: You could use sklearn's LabelEncoder for it, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915813/convert-text-columns-into-numbers-in-sklearn) post for details

Comment: Without seeing your full dataset (all columns), it's not possible to advise on all data types.  It appears as though pandas has it right (from what I can see).  An IP address is certainly **not** and `int`, but rather a string, or `object`.

Comment: @S3DEV you are right, but my question is how do I use this type data?