# Correlation between two non-numeric columns in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, correlation

I get my data from an SQL query from the table to my pandas Dataframe. The data looks like:

```
        group  phone_brand
0      M32-38          小米
1      M32-38          小米
2      M32-38          小米
3      M29-31          小米
4      M29-31          小米
5      F24-26         OPPO
6      M32-38          酷派
7      M32-38          小米
8      M32-38         vivo
9      F33-42          三星
10     M29-31          华为
11     F33-42          华为
12     F27-28          三星
13     M32-38          华为
14       M39+         艾优尼
15     F27-28          华为
16     M32-38          小米
17     M32-38          小米
18       M39+          魅族
19     M32-38          小米
20     F33-42          三星
21     M23-26          小米
22     M23-26          华为
23     M27-28          三星
24     M29-31          小米
25     M32-38          三星
26     M32-38          三星
27     F33-42          三星
28     M32-38          三星
29     M32-38          三星
...       ...          ...
74809  M27-28          华为
74810  M29-31          TCL
```

Now I want to find the correlation and the frequency from these two columns and put this in a visualization with Matplotlib. I tried something like:

```
DataFrame.plot(style='o')
plt.show()
```

Now how can I visualize this correlation in the simplest way?

Comment: You must first label the categories in columns with numbers; don't know how the Chinese symbols will be read (but serlialization should help); and then look for correlation. A heatmap is a good way to visualize the correlation matrix. find inspiration here: [Heatmap](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10459/calculation-and-visualization-of-correlation-matrix-with-pandas)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To quickly get a correlation:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.factorize()[0]).corr()

                group  phone_brand
group        1.000000     0.427941
phone_brand  0.427941     1.000000
```

---

Heat map

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(pd.crosstab(df.group, df.phone_brand))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas.factorize() method which can get the numeric representation of an array by identifying distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the method piRSquared very clearly explained, you can use `LabelEncoder` which transforms the values into numeric form in order to make sure that the machine interprets the features correctly.

```
#Import label encoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

#label_encoder object 
le = LabelEncoder()

#Fit label encoder and return encoded labels
df['group'] = le.fit_transform(df['group'])

df['phone_brand'] = le.fit_transform(df['phone_brand'] )

#Finding correlation
df.corr()

#output for first 10 rows

               group     phone_brand
      group  1.00000         0.67391
phone_brand  0.67391         1.00000
```

After applying `LabelEncoder`, our DataFrame converted from this

```
     group  phone_brand
0   M32-38          小米
1   M32-38          小米
2   M32-38          小米
3   M29-31          小米
4   M29-31          小米
5   F24-26         OPPO
6   M32-38          酷派
7   M32-38          小米
8   M32-38         vivo
9   F33-42          三星
10  M29-31          华为
```

to this

```
   group    phone_brand
0      3              4
1      3              4
2      3              4
3      2              4
4      2              4
5      0              0
6      3              5
7      3              4
8      3              1
9      1              2
10     2              3
```

For multiple columns, you can go through the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn).