# Can't use numeric_only in corr()

Tags: python, pandas

From what I understand the `numeric_only` argument is deprecated in the `corr()` function, so that it is set to false. I have a dataset and some of the columns aren't numeric, so that I want to to have correlation of only the these numeric columns. However when I write `corr(numeric_only = True)` I get this type error,

> TypeError: corr() got an unexpected keyword argument 'numeric_only'

Tried other solutions and checking the documentation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correlation between two non-numeric columns in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002168/correlation-between-two-non-numeric-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 5):

This method is only available in pandas version 1.5.0 or higher.

You should update your package with

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```