# Scikit learn preprocessing LabelBinarizer with lambda function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying my hand on the Titanic dataset.

I would like to use the `LabelBinarizer` on a few columns and I would like to avoid using a for loop.

I am trying to use a `lambda` function but it doesn't work:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer 

pp = LabelBinarizer()

X = df['sex', 'embarked', 'alive'] df.apply(lambda X: pp.fit_transform())
```

And:

```
df[['sex','embarked','alive']]= df[['sex','embarked','alive']].apply(lambda x: pp.fit_transform(x))
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Note that `df.apply` is syntactic sugar for a Python `for-loop`. There is essentially no performance difference.

Comment: In the future, you should provide the error messages when something "doesn't work"; otherwise, your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that because you are passing three cols on the left, sklearn is getting confused.

**Alternative**

But as @unutbu said, there is no difference in performance between `df.apply` and `for` so I'd just use this:

```
for col in ['sex','embarked','alive']:
     df[col] = pp.fit_transform(df[col])
```

**But if you *really* do a one liner, here's how you do it (warning, massive overkill):**

Add another layer of indentation to the `fit`, `tranform` and `fit_transform` methods as the formatting doesn't work (should match the indentation of the `def __init__` method.

```
class MultiColumnLabelBinarizer:
    def __init__(self,columns = None):
        self.columns = columns # array of column names to encode`

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self # not relevant here

    def transform(self,X):
        '''
        Transforms columns of X specified in self.columns using
        LabelEncoder(). If no columns specified, transforms all
        columns in X.
        '''
        output = X.copy()
        if self.columns is not None:
            for col in self.columns:
                output[col] = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(output[col])
        else:
            for colname,col in output.iteritems():
                output[colname] = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(col)
        return output

    def fit_transform(self,X,y=None):
        return self.fit(X,y).transform(X)

df = MultiColumnLabelBinarizer(columns = ['embarked','alive']).fit_transform(df)
```

Source: [Label encoding across multiple columns in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, much appreciated!