# Label encoding multiple columns with the same category

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["France", "Italy", "Belgium"], ["Italy", "France", "Belgium"]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df = df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
print(df)
```

It currently outputs:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  1  0  0
```

My goal is to make it output something like this by passing in the columns I want to share categorial values:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  1  0  2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass [`axis=1`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to call `LabelEncoder().fit_transform` once for each row.
(By default, `df.apply(func)` calls `func` once for each column).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["France", "Italy", "Belgium"], 
                        ["Italy", "France", "Belgium"]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])

encoder = LabelEncoder()

df = df.apply(encoder.fit_transform, axis=1)
print(df)
```

yields

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  2  1  0
```

---

Alternatively, you could use make the data of [`category` dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) and use the category codes as labels:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["France", "Italy", "Belgium"], 
                        ["Italy", "France", "Belgium"]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])

stacked = df.stack().astype('category')
result = stacked.cat.codes.unstack()
print(result)
```

also yields

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  2  1  0
```

This should be significantly faster since it does not require calling `encoder.fit_transform` once for each row (which might give terrible performance if you have lots of rows).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `pd.factorize`.

```
df = df.stack()
df[:] = pd.factorize(df)[0]
df.unstack()

   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  1  0  2
```

In case you want to `encode` only some columns in the dataframe then:

```
temp = df[['a', 'b']].stack()
temp[:] = temp.factorize()[0]
df[['a', 'b']] = temp.unstack()

   a  b        c
0  0  1  Belgium
1  1  0  Belgium
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. It gives me
0  a    0
   b    1
   c    2
1  a    3
   b    0
   c    2

Comment: @Martin: Check that you don't have a typo in your original `df` -- in particular "Italy" on the second row.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I forgot I tried swapping out Italy with Sweden in the first row. What I meant with this question was it should apply for all rows, which the second method in the first answer does, although I can see the ambiguity in my definition now.

Answer (score 1):

If the encoding order doesn't matter, you can do:

```
df_new = (         
    pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns,
                 data=LabelEncoder()
                 .fit_transform(df.values.flatten()).reshape(df.shape))
)

df_new
Out[27]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  2  1  0
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the mapping here? And: I actually think you solved a problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51030443/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using categorical data. Similar to @unutbu's but preserves ordering of factorization. In other words, the first value found will have code 0.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["France", "Italy", "Belgium"],
                        ["Italy", "France", "Belgium"]],
                  columns=["a", "b", "c"])

# get unique values in order
vals = df.T.stack().unique()

# convert to categories and then extract codes
for col in df:
    df[col] = pd.Categorical(df[col], categories=vals)
    df[col] = df[col].cat.codes

print(df)

   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  1  0  2
```

Comment: `pd.factorize()` does the exact same thing na ?

Comment: @Dark, That's true. The only reason you'd choose this solution over factorize is you intend to use categorical features (e.g. validation) and code view is just an alternative representation.