# keras pandas column value to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I have column like username

```
UserName , exam, score
Peter, 1, 70
Richard, 2, 80
Peter, 2, 60
```

...

would like to convert sth like below and pass as input array for model
UserName , exam,score

```
1,1,70
2,2,80
1,2,60
```

i can create a new col and do mapping by {'Peter':'1','Richard':'2'....}
but any smarter code can do this?
or Keras have some API to do that
I have around 100 user name in the column

Actually I also think so use function concept like below

```
def NameToInt(pd):
    listName=[]
    i=0
    for x in pd.unique():
        listName.append('X':'i')
        i=i+1
    return listName

Thanks
```

Comment: I'd say the duplicate provided by @jezrael is incorrect. How is it a duplicate?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski - Why do you think so?

Comment: @jezrael The author needs to encode categorical variables as integers. Moreover, it is desired that the transformation has an easy inverse. How the provided duplicate answers helps in that? LabelEncoder from scikit-learn is what is needed here.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski - be free add link to dupes, obviusly more solutions is possible. Or give me link, i can add it to dupes.

Comment: @jezrael I could not find something that would directly answer the question, but this one is fairly good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn Here's an exact solution: https://gist.github.com/tracek/463f85eed935440ba0193f33547cef45

Comment: @LukaszTracewskThanks, LabelEncoder is what I want