# How to Label encode multiple non-contiguous dataframe columns

Tags: scikit-learn

I am having a pandas dataframe with multiple columns (some of them non-contiguous) which would need to be label encoded. From my understanding of the LabelEncoder class, for each column I would need to use a different LabelEncoder object. I am using the code below (list_of_string_cols in the code below is a list of all the columns which needs to be label encoded)

```
for col in list_of_string_cols:
      labelenc = LabelEncoder()
      train_X[col] = labelenc.fit_transform(train_X[col])
      test_X[col] = labelenc.transform(test_X[col])
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's correct.

Since LabelEncoder was primarily made to deal with labels and not features, so it allowed only a single column at a time.

Up until the current version of scikit-learn (0.19.2), what you are using is the correct way of encoding multiple columns. See this question which also does what you are doing:

- [Label encoding across multiple columns in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn)

From next version onwards (0.20), [OrdinalEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) can be used to encode all categorical feature columns at once.