# Why am I getting a score of 0.0 when finding the score of test data using Gaussian NB classifier?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian

I have two different data sets. One for training my classifier and the other one is for testing. Both the datasets are text files with two columns separated by a ",".  FIrst column (numbers) is for the independent variable (group) and the second column is for the dependent variable.

**Training data set**

(just few lines for example. there are no empty lines between each row):

```
EMI3776438,1
EMI3776438,1
EMI3669492,1
EMI3752004,1
```

**Testing data setup**

(as you can see, i have picked data from the training data to be sure that the score surely can't be zero)

```
EMI3776438,1
```

Code in Python 3.6:

```
# #all the import statements have been ignored to keep the code short
# #loading the training data set

training_file_path=r'C:\Users\yyy\Desktop\my files\python\Machine learning\Carepack\modified_columns.txt'

from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

training_file_data =  pandas.read_table(training_file_path, 
                                        header=None, 
                                        names=['numbers','group'],
                                        sep=',')

training_file_data = training_file_data.apply(le.fit_transform)

features = ['numbers']

x = training_file_data[features]
y = training_file_data["group"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
training_x,testing_x, training_y, testing_y = train_test_split(x, y, 
                                                        random_state=0,
                                                        test_size=0.1)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

gnb= GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(training_x, training_y)

# #loading the testing data 
testing_final_path=r"C:\Users\yyy\Desktop\my files\python\Machine learning\Carepack\testing_final.txt"
testing_sample_data=pandas.read_table(testing_final_path, 
                                      sep=',',
                                      header=None, 
                                      names=['numbers','group'])

testing_sample_data = testing_sample_data.apply(le.fit_transform)

category = ["numbers"]

testing_sample_data_x = testing_sample_data[category]

# #finding the score of the test data
print(gnb.score(testing_sample_data_x, testing_sample_data["group"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the above data samples dont show how many classes are there in it. You need to describe more about it.

Secondly, you are calling `le.fit_transform` again on test data which will forget all the training samples mappings from strings to numbers. The `LabelEncoder` le will start encoding the test data again from scratch, which will not be equal to how it mapped training data. So the input to `GaussianNB` is now incorrect and hence incorrect results.

Change that to:

```
testing_sample_data = testing_sample_data.apply(le.transform)
```

---

**UPDATE**:

I'm sorry I overlooked the fact that you had two columns in your data. `LabelEncoder` only works on a single column of data. For making it work on multiple pandas columns at once, look at the answers of following question:

- [Label encoding across multiple columns in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn)

If you are using the latest version of scikit (`0.20`) or can update to it, then you would not need any such hacks and directly use [the `OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder()

training_file_data = enc.fit_transform(training_file_data)
```

And during testing:

```
training_file_data = enc.transform(training_file_data)
```

Comment: I changed the line to what you had asked me to but there is a different error now. The error arises from the changed line.


**ValueError: ("y contains previously unseen labels: 'numbers'", 'occurred at index numbers')**