# How to convert string columns to numeric values without getting NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8pC1.png)

I have columns of strings and I have to convert it into values. I used this code
and unfortunately the `fillna` method don't work at this example.

How can I fix the problem?

Here's the head()

[Head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8pC1.png)

```
data['country_txt'] = data['country_txt'].astype('float64') 
data['city'] = data['city'].astype('float64')
```

I expected a normal result but the actual output is all fulled with NaN values:

country_txt        0 non-null float64
city               0 non-null float64

Comment: At the beginning I had these informations:

country_txt        170350 non-null object
city               169904 non-null object

Comment: We need more information... post `data.head()`

Comment: I edited the post you can find it in Head()

Comment: `country_txt` is a string, for example, `Mexico`. What do you expect "Mexico" `.astype(int)` to become?

Comment: I expect a randomly given numeric value to each given country. Do you have any proposed solution please?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Label encoding across multiple columns in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you need to map your strings to `integer` representations.

There are many different ways to do that.

#### 1 [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)

```
df['country_as_int'] = pd.factorize(df['country_txt'])[0]
```

#### 2 [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
f = LabelEncoder()
df['country_as_int'] = f.fit_transform(df['country_txt'])
```

#### 3 [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

```
df['country_as_int'] = np.unique(df['country_txt'], return_inverse=True)[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering me, but using this, I had an error: 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: @Amamra then use option #1. As an alternative, you can also reinforce `df['country_txt'].astype(str)` as to make `NaN`s a string.