# Linear regression with python use sklearn

Tags: python, linear-regression

i try to do Linear regression with python

For example

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [[6, 2], [8, 1], [10, 0], [14, 2], [18, 0]]
y = [[7], [9], [13], [17.5], [18]]
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x, y)
x_test = [[8, 2]]
```

Now the example_data like:

```
inches city  Pizza_Price
  5       A        10
  6       B        12
```

inches is a clear number but area is not.

How can I convert a city to a number for calculation？

How to classify parameters like city into numbers for calculation？

Comment: Did you try `LabelEncoder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
cities = ['A','B','C','B'] # for example

le.fit(cities)
cities = le.transform(cities)
print(cities)
```

Output:

> [0, 1, 2, 1]

[Label Encoder explanation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use pd.get_dummies() to convert each city into a binary value. Label encoder will assign an integer value to the variable which will make interpreting the regression formula difficult and possibly skewed. Remember to drop one of the dummy variables to avoid multi-collinearity.

Answer (score 0):

From your data shown in `example_data`, it looks like you are working with data in a Pandas `DataFrame`. So, I would suggest another possible approach to answering your question

Here is some data I generated in the same format as yours but with extra rows

```
d = [
    ['inches','city','Pizza_Price'],
    [5,'A',10],
    [6,'B',12],
    [7,'C',15],
    [8,'D',11],
    [9,'B',12],
    [10,'C',17],
    [11,'D',16]
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(d[1:], columns=d[0])

print(df)
   inches city  Pizza_Price
0       5    A           10
1       6    B           12
2       7    C           15
3       8    D           11
4       9    B           12
5      10    C           17
6      11    D           16
```

The conversion of the `city` column into integers can be done using `LabelEncoder` (as shown in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51030443/4057186)), per @Wen-Ben's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821315/linear-regression-with-python-use-sklearn#comment98308723_55821315)

```
df['city'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['city'],
                        data=LabelEncoder().fit_transform(
                            df['city'].values.flatten())
                        )

print(df)
   inches  city  Pizza_Price
0       5     0           10
1       6     1           12
2       7     2           15
3       8     3           11
4       9     1           12
5      10     2           17
6      11     3           16
```

**Step 1.** Perform the [train-test split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to get the training and testing data `X_train`, `y_train`, etc.

```
features = ['inches', 'city']
target = 'Pizza_Price'

X = df[features]
y = df[target]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    test_size=0.33,
                                                    random_state=42)

# (OPTIONAL) Check number of rows in X and y of each split
print(len(X_train), len(y_train))
print(len(X_test), len(y_test))
4 4
3 3
```

**Step 2.** (Optional) Append a column to your source `DataFrame` (`example_data`) that shows which rows are used in training and testing

```
df['Type'] = 'Test'
df.loc[X_train.index, 'Type'] = 'Train'
```

**Step 3.** Instantiate the `LinearRegression` model and train the model using the training dataset - see this link from `sklearn` [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

```
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**Step 4.** Now, make out-of-sample predictions on the testing data and (optionally) append the predicted values as a separate column to the `example_data`

- the rows used in the training dataset will have no prediction so they will be assigned `NaN`
- the rows used in the testing dataset will have a prediction

```
df['Predicted_Pizza_Price'] = np.nan
df.loc[X_test.index, 'Predicted_Pizza_Price'] = model.predict(X_test)

print(df)
   inches  city  Pizza_Price   Type  Predicted_Pizza_Price
0       5     0           10   Test                   11.0
1       6     1           12   Test                   11.8
2       7     2           15  Train                    NaN
3       8     3           11  Train                    NaN
4       9     1           12  Train                    NaN
5      10     2           17   Test                   14.0
6      11     3           16  Train                    NaN
```

**Step 5.** Generate model evaluation metrics (see point number 15. from [here](https://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning-evaluate-linear-regression-model/))

- we will generate a Pandas `DataFrame` showing both the (a) model evaluation metrics and (b) model properties - the Linear Regression coefficients and the intercept
- we will first generate a Python dictionary that contains all these values and then [convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) the dictionary to a Pandas `DataFrame`

Create a blank dictionary to hold the model properties (coefficient, intercept) and evaluation metrics

```
dict_summary = {}
```

Append coefficient and intercept to dictionary

```
for m,feature in enumerate(features):
    dict_summary['Coefficient ({})' .format(feature)] = model.coef_[m]
dict_summary['Intercept'] = model.intercept_
```

Append evaluation metrics to dictionary

```
y_test = df.loc[X_test.index, 'Pizza_Price'].values
y_pred = df.loc[X_test.index, 'Predicted_Pizza_Price'].values
dict_summary['Mean Absolute Error (MAE)'] = metrics.mean_absolute_error(
                                                                y_test, y_pred)
dict_summary['Mean Squared Error (MSE)'] = metrics.mean_squared_error(
                                                                y_test, y_pred)
dict_summary['Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)'] = np.sqrt(
                                    metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
                                                        )
```

Convert dictionary into summary `DataFrame` showing regression model properties and evaluation metrics

```
df_metrics = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_summary, orient='index', columns=['value'])
df_metrics.index.name = 'metric'
df_metrics.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Output of model evaluation `DataFrame`

```
print(df_metrics)
                           metric     value
0            Coefficient (inches)  0.466667
1              Coefficient (city)  0.333333
2                       Intercept  8.666667
3       Mean Absolute Error (MAE)  1.400000
4        Mean Squared Error (MSE)  3.346667
5  Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)  1.829390
```

Using this approach, since you have results in Pandas 2 `DataFrame`s, Pandas tools can be used to visualize the results of the regression analysis.