# Aggregate and Convert categorical data to numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a data frame df_train which has a column sub_division.

The values in the column is look like below

```
ABC_commercial,
ABC_Private,
Test ROM DIV,
ROM DIV,
TEST SEC R&OM
```

I am trying to 
1. convert anything starts with ABC* to a number (for ex: 1)
2. convert anything contains ROM and R&OM to a number (for ex: 2)

Thanks in advance.

Expected result:

```
1,
1,
2,
2,
2
```

Comment: the magic word is called Label encoder for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
m1 = df['col'].str.startswith('ABC')
m2 = df['col'].str.contains('ROM|R&OM')

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1,2], default='no match')
#if need all numbers
#df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1,2], default=0)
print (df)
               col new
0  ABC_commercial,   1
1     ABC_Private,   1
2    Test ROM DIV,   2
3         ROM DIV,   2
4    TEST SEC R&OM   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. Remember you will get `NaN` if there is no match. You can add `else` case in the `converter` function to get default value.

```
def converter(v):
    if v.startswith('ABC'):
        return 1
    elif any(i in v for i in ['ROM', 'R&OM']):
        return 2

df['sub_division'] = df['sub_division'].apply(converter)
print(df.head(10))
```

output:

```
   sub_division
0             1
1             1
2             2
3             2
4             2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['col'].str.startswith('ABC'), 'col'] = 1
df.loc[df['col'].str.contains(r'ROM|R&OM', na=False), 'col'] = 2
```