# `LabelEncoder` for each column separately or one across all columns?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I just read this post [Label encoding across multiple columns in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn) where the author states:

> As the dataframe has many (50+) columns, I want to avoid creating a
>   `LabelEncoder` object for each column; I'd rather just have one big
>   `LabelEncoder` objects that works across *all* my columns of data.

Is it sensible to do this and why?

For me it is more natural to have a separate `LabelEncoder` for each column of your dataframe with categorical data.

What happens (in the case of the one `LabelEncoder` across all columns) when you encounter unseen data in a specific column?

Comment: I'd not consider it sensible, but no word about this from any of the core developers of sklearn answering there, so I'm thoroughly confused now. Also, does it make sense to `LabelEncode` *features*, as opposed to labels or classes?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan, regarding your question, I think that the author means the same as you you (labels/classes).

Comment: Yes, that is possibly the case. Out of curiosity, do you know any practical use-case where 50 mulit-class labels are simultaneously predicted from a single sample? I know the NLP case where a document can have many labels, but that's binary class, present or not present

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan, I do not have sth now in my mind I think ;)

Comment: @desertnaut, what is your opinion on the question of my post above?