# How to run 2 pipelines in parallel in scikit-learn or Neuraxle?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, neuraxle

I want to create a simple pipeline with `neuraxle` (I know I can use other libraries but I want to use `neuraxle`) where I want to clean data, split it, train 2 models and compare them.

I want my pipeline to do something like this:

```py
p = Pipeline([
    PreprocessData(),
    SplitData(),
    (some magic to start the training of both models with the split of the previous step)
    ("model1", model1(params))
    ("model2", model2(params))
    (evaluate)
])
```

I don't know if it's even possible because I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Also I tried using other models than those from `sklearn` (e.g. `catboost`, `xgboost` ...) and I get the error

> AttributeError: 'CatBoostRegressor' object has no attribute 'setup'

I thought about creating a class for the models but I won't use the hyperparam search of `neuraxle`

Comment: Always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can do something like this:

```
p = Pipeline([
    PreprocessData(),
    ColumnTransformer([
        (0, model1(params)),  # Model 1 will receive Column 0 of data
        ([1, 2], model2(params)),  # Model 2 will receive Column 1 and 2 of data
    ], n_dimension=2, n_jobs=2),
    (evaluate)
])
```

The flow of data will be split into two.

The `n_jobs=2` should create two threads. It may also be possible to pass a custom class for putting back the data together using the `joiner` argument. We'll be releasing some changes soon, so this should work properly. For now, the pipeline works with 1 thread.

For what regards your `CatBoostRegressor` model that is like sklearn but that doesn't come from sklearn, can you try to do `SKLearnWrapper(model1(params))` instead of simply `model1(params)` when declaring your model in the pipeline? Probably that Neuraxle didn't recognize the model as a scikit-learn model (which is a BaseEstimator object in scikit-learn) even if your object had the same API as scikit-learn's BaseEstimator. So you may need to use the `SKLearnWrapper` manually around your model or to code your own similar wrapper to adapt your class to Neuraxle.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60302366/2476920

---

**EDIT**:

You can use the [ParallelQueuedFeatureUnion](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.distributed.streaming.html#neuraxle.distributed.streaming.ParallelQueuedFeatureUnion) class of Neuraxle. Example coming soon.

Also see this parallel pipeline usage example: https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/examples/parallel/plot_streaming_pipeline.html#sphx-glr-examples-parallel-plot-streaming-pipeline-py