# How to decode LabelEncoder implemented column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, preprocessor, sklearn-pandas, label-encoding

I'm having a [dataset](https://github.com/Samar-080301/Exploratory_Data_Analysis/blob/main/train.csv). Where I was practicing feature engineering by converting categorical objects to numbers, with the following lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
df = pd.read_csv(r'train.csv',index_col='Id')
print(df.shape)
df.head()
colsNum = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
colsObj = df.columns.difference(colsNum)

df[colsNum] = df[colsNum].fillna(df[colsNum].mean()//1)
df[colsObj] = df[colsObj].fillna(df[colsObj].mode().iloc[0])

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 
for col in colsObj:
    df[col] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df[col])
df.head()
for col in colsObj:
    df[col] = label_encoder.inverse_transform(df[col])
df.head()
```

But here the `inverse_tranform()` wasn't returning the original dataset. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one encoder per column - you cannot encode all columns with the same encoder:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
df = pd.read_csv(r'train.csv', index_col='Id')
print(df.shape)

colsNum = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
colsObj = df.columns.difference(colsNum)

df[colsNum] = df[colsNum].fillna(df[colsNum].mean()//1)
df[colsObj] = df[colsObj].fillna(df[colsObj].mode().iloc[0])
print(df.head())

encoder = {}

for col in colsObj:
    encoder[col] = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    df[col] = encoder[col].fit_transform(df[col])
print(df.head())

for col in colsObj:
    df[col] = encoder[col].inverse_transform(df[col])
print(df.head())
```

You can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939145/1453508) for further details.