# sklearn throws ValueError: bad input shape (600000, 24)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Below is a piece of my code for Label Encoding. While implementing Label Encoder for one column of the Dataframe at a time, it worked fine. But, when I tried to implement on whole categorical features at once `sklearn` throws

> **ValueError: bad input shape (600000, 24). I'm not able to find any specific reason for that**.

```
df = pd.read_csv("../inputs/cat-in-the-dat-train-folds.csv")
    
# extracting the categorical features 
cat_features = [x for x in df.columns if x not in ( "id", "target", "kflod")]
    
for col in cat_features:
    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(str).fillna("NONE")
df_train = df[df["kfold"] != fold].reset_index(drop=True)
df_valid = df[df["kfold"] == fold].reset_index(drop=True)
lbl_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
full_cat_data = pd.concat(
        [df_train[cat_features], df_valid[cat_features]],
        axis=0)
lbl_enc.fit(full_cat_data)
x_train = lbl_enc.transform(df_train[cat_features])
x_valid = lbl_enc.transform(df_valid[cat_features])
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939145/8505949) could help you.

Comment: In the `cat_features` listcomp, is `"kflod"` intentional or is that a typo of `"kfold"`?

Answer (score 0):

[sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) only takes a 1D array as a parameter.

To fit multiple columns, use [sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html) which can take multi-dimensional data with *[n_samples, n_features]* (as per the documentation)

In your example, try replacing `lbl_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()` with `lbl_enc = preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()` and that should work.

See this answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39317/difference-between-ordinalencoder-and-labelencoder/64177) for more information on the difference between LabelEncoder and OrdinalEncoder

**Additional resources**:

- [Label encoding across multiple columns in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn/31939145#31939145)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: @RakeshKumarKuwar Of course! Was this able to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I implemented ordinal Encoder for transforming the whole categorical data & it worked. Although, not getting great accuracy with Logres, will try with the xgboost model. I sincerely appreciate your help.